# Where are bash variables defined?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I find the file that a bash variable is defined there?

Assume the `echo` command shows

```
$ echo $DB_ROOT
/home/mahmood/db-4.0
```

Now, how can I find the file that this variable has been defined there? I have to say that I have not defined it in `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a large number of places where it *could* be defined.

For a full explanation, you need to look at the `bash` manpage, under `INVOCATION`, but I have to warn you that it will probably give you a headache before you get it all figured out :-)

Depending on how the shell is invoked and what files exist, it may be one or more of:

- `/etc/profile`.
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `~/.bash_profile`.
- `~/.bash_login`.
- `~/.profile`.
- `~/.bashrc`.
- whatever is specified with the `--rcfile` option.
- whatever is specified with the `BASH_ENV` environment variable.
- whatever is specified with the `ENV` environment variable.
- any file called from the preceding files.

---

For what it's worth, I usually make sure I have a `~/.bash_profile` (since that's the highest priority of the set `{~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile}` - it will only process the *first* that it finds in that group).

I also make sure I have `~/.bashrc` and that `~/.bash_profile` sources it at the end.

That way, `~/.bash_profile` holds only the stuff that I need in login shells and `~/.bashrc` holds the stuff I want in *every* shell. You just have to make sure that the latter doesn't hold any "cumulative" commands (like adding something to the end of the path).

There's other ways to set it up, especially if you're using different shells and have to share profiles among them, but that scheme above is the easiest I've found in `bash`-only setups.

Comment: I found another difinition in `~/.profile`. I removed it and `source`ed again. However still the `echo` command shows the variable

Comment: ok I found that I have to logoff/login because of `.profile'. Thanks man